# Processing heating data in influxdb

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux

I have data stored in influxdb recording when my heating and cooling systems turn on and off. It forms a table like:

```
Time, furnace on (boolean), fan on (Boolean), cooling on (boolean)
```

But there are only entries when the state changes. I’m having trouble modifying the data into the forms I want:

1. time on, time off data so I can annotate grafana temperature graphs
2. Calculating the total time active for arbitrary times. This is to calculate carbon used or estimate my house’s insulation.

What’s the idiomatic way of doing this in Flux?

I tried reading the documentation to better understand flux’s functional philosophy.

I looked into using “reduce” but I can’t figure out how to pass more state than a running total.

The sql support for influxdb doesn’t have the advanced features necessary to express these queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [stateDuration](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/monitor-states/#example-query-with-stateduration) function.

```
from(bucket: "yourBucket")
    |> range(start: -5m)
    |> stateDuration(fn: (r) => r._value == "1", column: "furnace_on", unit: 1s)   // searches the yourBucket bucket over the past 5 minutes to find how many seconds a furnace has been on
    
    
from(bucket: "yourBucket")
    |> range(start: -5m)
    |> stateDuration(fn: (r) => r._value == "1", column: "fan_on", unit: 1s)   // searches the yourBucket bucket over the past 5 minutes to find how many seconds a fan has been on
    
    
from(bucket: "yourBucket")
    |> range(start: -5m)
    |> stateDuration(fn: (r) => r._value == "1", column: "cooling_on", unit: 1s) // searches the yourBucket bucket over the past 5 minutes to find how many seconds a cooling has been on
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to `stateDuration`! I gave it a shot and it's /almost/ doing what I need.  What I noticed is if I have a table like:

| _time                        | aux_heat1 |
| 12/15/2022 02:59:54 | true           |
| 12/15/2022 03:05:54 | true           |
| 12/15/2022 03:08:54 | false          |

` |> stateDuration(fn: (r) => r.auxHeat1, unit: 1m, column: "auxHeat1OnTime")`

returns:


* 12/15/2022 02:59:54  0 minutes
* 12/15/2022 03:05:54  6 minutes
* 12/15/2022 03:08:54  -1 minutes (not 9 min?)

any ideas?